# Use CVS and GIT together in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, cvs

I already have a CVS and that cvs is used to share the source among other developers. But I need to keep a track of my source code changes separately. Moving the project from cvs to git is not practicable here.. and you may think that why 2 versioning controls. Any way I need to have a separate repository. I have tried git with eclipse. It is ok. I want to know how I can use both my personal git repository and cvs together in eclipse. (For example, when I commit my changes in eclipse, Team -> commit .. How can I separately commit to both cvs and git..and whenever I need to see the history in eclipse, separately git and cvs.. .Also when CVS server is not supporting, I can work with my local git repo as well. ) I need to handle all in eclipse IDE. Any one give any tutorial or links for my solution, it is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a git repo directly within your sources, but Eclipse would still be set on using CVS (and cannot show you both git and cvs commands at the same time).

That means you go on committing with CVS and Eclipse, but would need to commit (locally) in Git with an external tool (either a simple command-line session, or any GUI you want, like [GitHub for Windows](http://windows.github.com/) or [SourceTree](http://www.atlassian.com/software/sourcetree/overview))

Comment: Thank very much for your answer. I was trying to find a way.. As you mentioned, I ll have to use another tool for that :( .

Answer (score 0):

It actually is possible, if you create a dummy Eclipse project and designate the git repository at the workspace root (.git directory at same level as all projects in the workspace). This way when you make commits from this project, all projects in the workspace are its members and you can keep the members themselves connected to cvs.

You can create such repository by first creating the dummy project, and (Team->Share) sharing it via git using the Configure Git Repository dialog. Select “Use or create repository in parent folder” and explicitly remove the project folder from the "Create Repository" line after checking (checkbox) the project from the list of available projects.

After pressing "Create Repository" the project directory suffix will reappear, but remove it again before pressing Finish. In my version of Eclipse pressing Finish will hang, and I must terminate Eclipse to restart it.

After restarting the dummy project can be used to Commit files in all the other projects while the other projects remain connected to cvs.

[Screenshot of “Use or create repository in parent folder” view when pathname has been entered by pressing "Create Repository" and then (corrected again before pressing) Finish.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKrIA.png)